# How I can use map() to display array values once in a table?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, datatable

thanks in advance for any patience to read my issue. I'm trying to get displayed some data in a table in the browser. For now I want to take my object and console.log it, so that later I can put in the table.
I have this object as a first test :

```
CedentePrestatore: "GEA 2 s.r.l."
CessionarioCommittente: "RENATO"
DataDoc: "2019-12-21"
Importo: "30.71"
TipoDoc: "TD01"
```

Starting from it, I'm trying to fill headers and rows like this, so in the frontend I can grab these data:

```
const data ={
  headers: ["TipoDoc.","DataDoc.","Importo","CedentePrestatore","CessionarioCommittente"],
  rows: new Array(10).fill(undefined).map((Array) => {
    return [
        tempDati
    ];
  })
};

app.get("/data",(req,res)=>{
    res.json({
        headers:data.headers,
        rows:data.rows
    });
});
```

What I got so far are headers and rows which got displayed 10 times as the array length (which at the end should be also the table lenght). I'm wondering what method() or different procedure I could use to make it displayed properly once, and then replicate the fill for each array I would get.. In the table every array should correspond to a row. Any idea?

The actual result console.log():

```
{"headers": 
["TipoDoc.","DataDoc.","Importo","CedentePrestatore","CessionarioCommittente"],"rows": 
[[{"TipoDoc":"TD01","DataDoc":"2019-12-21","Importo":"30.71","CedentePrestatore":"GEA 2 
 s.r.l.","CessionarioCommittente":"RENATO"}],[{"TipoDoc":"TD01","DataDoc":"2019-12- 
21","Importo":"30.71","CedentePrestatore":"GEA 2 
 s.r.l.","CessionarioCommittente":"RENATO"}],[{"TipoDoc":"TD01","DataDoc":"2019-12- 
21","Importo":"30.71","CedentePrestatore":"GEA 2 
 s.r.l.","CessionarioCommittente":"RENATO"}],[{"TipoDoc":"TD01","DataDoc":"2019-12- 
21","Importo":"30.71","CedentePrestatore":"GEA 2 
 s.r.l.","CessionarioCommittente":"RENATO"}],[{"TipoDoc":"TD01","DataDoc":"2019-12- 
21","Importo":"30.71","CedentePrestatore":"GEA 2 
 s.r.l.","CessionarioCommittente":"RENATO"}],[{"TipoDoc":"TD01","DataDoc":"2019-12- 
21","Importo":"30.71","CedentePrestatore":"GEA 2 
 s.r.l.","CessionarioCommittente":"RENATO"}],[{"TipoDoc":"TD01","DataDoc":"2019-12- 
21","Importo":"30.71","CedentePrestatore":"GEA 2 
 s.r.l.","CessionarioCommittente":"RENATO"}],[{"TipoDoc":"TD01","DataDoc":"2019-12- 
21","Importo":"30.71","CedentePrestatore":"GEA 2 
 s.r.l.","CessionarioCommittente":"RENATO"}],[{"TipoDoc":"TD01","DataDoc":"2019-12- 
21","Importo":"30.71","CedentePrestatore":"GEA 2 
 s.r.l.","CessionarioCommittente":"RENATO"}],[{"TipoDoc":"TD01","DataDoc":"2019-12- 
21","Importo":"30.71","CedentePrestatore":"GEA 2 
 s.r.l.","CessionarioCommittente":"RENATO"}]]}
```

Comment: Instead of `return [ tempDati ];` try `return [tempDati.TipoDoc, tempDati.DataDoc, tempDati.Importo, tempDati.CedentePrestatore, tempDati.CessionarioCommittente]`

Comment: Try just `return tempDati` without the `[ ]` around it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `return [tempDati]` try

```
return [...Object.values(tempDati)]
```